# Plotting predefined density functions using ggplot and R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have three data sets of different lengths and I would like to plot density functions of all three on the same plot. This is straight forward with base graphics:

```
n <- c(rnorm(10000), rnorm(10000))
a <- c(rnorm(10001), rnorm(10001, 0, 2))
p <- c(rnorm(10002), rnorm(10002, 2, .5))

plot(density(n))
lines(density(a))
lines(density(p))
```

Which gives me something like this:

[alt text http://www.cerebralmastication.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/density.png](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/density.png)

But I really want to do this with GGPLOT2 because I want to add other features that are only available with GGPLOT2. It seems that GGPLOT really wants to take my empirical data and calculate the density for me. And it gives me a bunch of lip because my data sets are of different lengths. So how do I get these three densities to plot in GGPLOT2?

Comment: Just wondering ... why do you always capitalize ggplot2?

Comment: I actually don't... it's my little finger. It just jumps over there and presses the shift key without my permission. :) I think it is an unconscious result of typing a lot of acronyms in caps all day long. I'm make a conscious effort to leave it in lower case. I do the same thing with plyr (even as I typed that I have to backspace and make it lower case). Hadley already busted my chops for mixing case + underscore in my variable names in my code. You guys are going to make me more tidy and easy to read if I'm not careful!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The secret to happiness in ggplot2 is to put everything in the "long" (or what I guess matrix oriented people would call "sparse") format:

```
df <- rbind(data.frame(x="n",value=n),
            data.frame(x="a",value=a),
            data.frame(x="p",value=p))
qplot(value, colour=x, data=df, geom="density")
```

If you don't want colors:

```
qplot(value, group=x, data=df, geom="density")
```

Comment: you made my night so much better. I was struggling with this and could not figure it out. Thank you so much.